# data structure for bigger number of files

Tags: structure, directory

I'm looking for effective way to sort albums with songs. I have around 10000 and growing albums with approx 10 songs in every album. So that means 100000 files.

Now I do not want to store all folders (albums) in one main folder, but I'm looking for a better way to store it. All folders are hierarchy equal, so I was thinking to group folder by initials or just simply pack 1000 folders in another folder. But a lot of people says that this could be messy..

What do you suggest?

(I know it's not directly linked to programming, but I think that data storage should be also important)

Comment: You could delete all the music you illegally downloaded, and then the number of files would be smaller. ;)

Comment: Voting to move to [superusers](http://superusers.com). This is in no way even vaguely programming related; it's a question about how to organize your personal music collection. As such, it's off topic here.

Comment: @Ken: This is over 2 years old though, so we don't want to migrate it.  Flagging for closing is fine though, I just wanted to let you know why it's not going to be moved.

Answer (score 2):

Write a content management program into which you can load your mp3s, have it move the file to a folder in its structure, and write an entry to a database.

Have the database store the information, including physical path.

Query against the database when you are searching, and have your management program provide an option to open the path in Windows Explorer (or just link it to your music player).

Comment: My main care is which is faster/better? more files in directory and less directories OR less files in dir and more dirs..

Comment: In general, in Windows XP, you will be best served by having a good balance.  Folders start to slow down significantly once they pass ~900 items.  I believe that folders and files are equivalent in terms of 'items'.

Best bet: your structure should be like: Music -> Genres -> Artists -> Albums.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your trying to access these from the file system and not through some other software, you'd be best served to create a hierarchy that can be easily navigated.  I would use the initials as you suggested.

Group them by first letter, then second letter, as deep as you need to get small-ish groups.  You don't have to go the same number of levels for each group either.  "T" may go 5 levels in, but "Q" only one.